# Tizen Cannot read property 'getDefaultAdapter' of undefined

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

When I try to get bluetooth properties in tizen studio:

```
var bluetoothSwitchAppControl = new tizen.ApplicationControl('http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/edit', null, 'application/x-bluetooth-on-off');
var adapter = tizen.bluetooth.getDefaultAdapter();
```

I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDefaultAdapter' of undefined

What is the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's totally Okay. You don't need to solve anything. Most probably you are running the project on Tizen Wearable/Mobile **Emulator**.

tizen.bluetooth.getDefaultAdapter() and other relevant bluetooth functions would be undefined when you are deploying the app on Emulator, Cause Emulators don't support Bluetooth. When you would deploy the Project on Real Device it would work as expected.